# Drop a table column

Tags: php, mysql, sql-drop

Is the following correct?  I am getting an error.

```
<?php
        $form_id = $form->data['form_id'];
        $query = mysql_query("
        ALTER TABLE 'email_history' DROP '$form_id';
        ") or die(mysql_error());
        ?>
```

Comment: It should be: `ALTER TABLE email_history DROP COLUMN column_name;`

Comment: Hi, im using a dynamic value generated by the $form_id , it is equal to (the current column name selected), I have it sorted now, I just was using the wrong (')s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ` (backtick) to delimit object names in MySQL. Try that

```
ALTER TABLE `email_history` DROP `$form_id`;
```

Note, I don't know php, but you can't parametrise DDL (`ALTER TABLE` etc)

Comment: ahh thats got it, I was using ' s instead of ` s ,